# PHP automatically removes < and > from data in POST, why?

Tags: php, post

I have an input in form with value, eg:

```
Username <username@somedomain.com>
```

When i send form, php has in $_POST only:

```
Username
```

Where is remaining part of input? How to get it?

Comment: Right click the page -> View Source. Tada.

Comment: i checked it, its only username.

Answer (score 5):

Are you SURE that php is removing it?

If you're just printing a value using `echo $variable.` on a HTML page, the browser will hide it itself.

Check on the page source. It is probably being sent by php, but the browser is filtering it out.

If you want it to be displayed, you need to change `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`, like so:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($variable);
```

Comment: You should use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) instead of str_replace.

Comment: Nice to meet you, htmlspecialchars! Thanks, Cixate.

Comment: when i print_r($_POST) its just **Username**, strlen($_POST['to'][0]) == 8

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt PHP is removing it on its own.

It's likely that when you are displaying it, you are not converting the arrow characters in to html entities.

e.g. one way of displaying the value:

```
echo htmlentities($_POST['var'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```